# HTML5 to sync music with images

Tags: html

I'm playing a 4 second music loop using the HTML5 audio element.  At the same time I need to display 48 images, one after the other.  When the audio returns to the beginning of the loop, the image must return to frame 1.

I need to synch the images to the music.

This is not a problem for a few iterations of the loop, but any slight delay in the processing of the music results in a slight loss of sync with the images - which increases over time.

Any thoughts on the best way of maintaining sync please?

Comment: HTML is not a programming language. To do such a thing would require javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The audio element is throwing a [timeupdate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/timeupdate) event. You could use that to synchronize the currently shown image via JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried logging the timeupdate event but it doesn't appear to update quickly enough to allow me to show my 48 images in 4 secs.  It only responds 18 times in 4 seconds.